# YLScsDrawing Antialiased Edges

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, antialiasing

There's a neat little library called [YLScsDrawing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36145/Free-Image-Transformation) that allows you to skew a bitmap between four corners, and then draw it. Unfortunately, whenever I attempt this, my rectangular bitmap always has incredibly aliased edges, even with `IsBilinearInterpolation = True`. How could I go about changing this library so that it antialiases the edges?

An example of what I mean can be found below. Look at the top of the green line.

[image: Look at the top of the line above the clock for an example of aliasing]